# How to pass multiple arguments to map()?

Tags: python, numpy

Would you help me understand if it possible to call map with multiple arguments ?

My goal is to calculate the following:

```
numpy.mean(array,axis=1)
numpy.var(array,axis=0)
numpy.std(array,axis=None)
```

I can call `map` with list comprehension, but struggling to pass **named argument** to it

```
print "{}\n{}\n{}".format(*[ map(x,array) for x in [numpy.mean,numpy.var,numpy.std]])
```

Comment: What do you mean with named arguments?

Comment: @Dani Keyword argument, i.e. `axis`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using map with multiple args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646996/using-map-with-multiple-args)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> array = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> array
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> func_list = [
        partial(numpy.mean, axis=1), 
        partial(numpy.var, axis=0), 
        partial(numpy.std, axis=None)
    ]
>>> print(*map(lambda x:x(array), func_list), sep='\n')
[1.5 5.5 9.5]
[10.66666667 10.66666667 10.66666667 10.66666667]
3.452052529534663
```

Another way:

```
>>> func_list = [(numpy.mean, numpy.var, numpy.std), 
                 ({'axis':1}, {'axis':0}, {'axis':None})]

>>> print(*map(lambda f,kw: f(array, **kw), *func_list), sep='\n')
[1.5 5.5 9.5]
[10.66666667 10.66666667 10.66666667 10.66666667]
3.452052529534663
```

A slight variation of the above:

```
>>> func_list = [
        (numpy.mean, {'axis':1}), 
        (numpy.var, {'axis':0}), 
        (numpy.std, {'axis':None})
    ]
>>> print(*map(lambda f,kw: f(array, **kw), *zip(*func_list)), sep='\n')
[1.5 5.5 9.5]
[10.66666667 10.66666667 10.66666667 10.66666667]
3.452052529534663
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the functions with a lambda expression:

```
def a(x): return numpy.mean(x,axis=1)
def b(x): return numpy.var(x,axis=0)
def c(x): return numpy.std(x,axis=None)

print ("{}\n{}\n{}".format(*[x(array) for x in [a,b,c]]))
```

in the lambda expression you can specify the arguments. If you have more informations you can specify this in the lambda expression as well. Example:

```
def a_1 (x,y): numpy.std(x,axis=y)
```

But then you need to pass this arguments as well. For example in a tuple

```
func_1 = (a_1, None) #Functionname and attribute
```

Comment: [Avoid named lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38381556/4518341). Use a `def` instead, or a partial like in [Sayandip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63330003/4518341)

Comment: Thank you, will it work for python2.7 ?  Im getting an error 
".../2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2716, in mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File ".../2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 52, in _mean
    rcount = _count_reduce_items(arr, axis)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 46, in _count_reduce_items
    items *= arr.shape[ax]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> array
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

Comment: I checked it with python 2.7 and it worked for me :)

Comment: ah ok i checked my function. I threw an arra with the map function. Remove the map function as i showd in my edit and the error won't be raised.